# SP-initiated and IdP-initiated SSO lands on different landing page

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I have SAML based SSO authenitcation set in Salesforce.

SSP Initiated and IDP initiated SSO lands on different landing pages.

I am aware that relay state parameter would decide the landng page for IDP initated SSO.

How can we check the SP initiated landing page and check as to ahy the difference is occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a default tab for your users? If so, then the SP-initiated landing page would automatically be that landing page, versus the default page "/home/home.jsp" that you'd get if you simply had a state of "/".

Comment: I wanted to land the users to a custom page after successful authentication. We are using SAML 2.0.  What has to be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Please reference Customize SAML Start, Error, Login, and Logout Pages section of [Single Sign-On Implementation Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_single_sign_on.pdf)

> If your identity provider uses SAML 1.1, the URL to direct the user to when single sign-on successfully completes (known as the start page). This URL can be absolute, such as https://na1.salesforce.com/001/o or it can be relative, such as /001/o. This URL must be an endpoint that accepts SAML authentication requests.
>
> **In SAML 2.0, the start page is the page the user attempted to access before they were authenticated. The SAML 2.0 start page must support Sp-init single sign-on.**
>
> If you are using SAML 2.0, you can also use the RelayState parameter to control where
> users get redirected after a successful login.

Comment: I wanted to land the users to a custom page after successful authentication. We are using SAML 2.0  What needs to be done ?

Comment: @BijilRavindran create a new question. And it's easy to google: [Using the StartURL Parameter](https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_start.htm&type=0)